# Samsung IAP - checking if an item is bought upon start up?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I just do not know how to use Samsung IAP!

I come from Google Play IAP where the IAP was pretty easy to implement. I took out all of that stuff and I started integrating the Samsung stuff. Now, I can make purchases, but what I don't understand is how to check if an item has been purchased.

My game has ads, and I have one non-consumable set up that will disable ads forever if purchased. As stated, I can purchase and disable the ads - the issue is that I want to check if that item has been purchased upon each start up, maybe in the on create. Otherwise, the ads come back upon the app closing down (I can use shared preferences, but if the app is uninstalled, the issue remains).

This is how it works in Google Play IAP. I have gone through the docs and the one example, and I understand that I can use doGetInboxList to see what items have been purchased.

However, as in the sample, this just asks for the group ID (no individual items), and even then, just says what and what isn't purchased in a list view. I have searched the code, but I can't even find where this is set. Regardless, programmitically I just want something.. anything! A boolean. Is this item with this id bought or not - yes or no. True or false. Have I missed something? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are close.
Take that sample from InboxListActivity and apply to your activity:

```
public class YourStartUpActivity extends Activity implements OnGetInboxListener
{
    private String  mItemGroupId = "100000xxxxxx";
    private int     mIapMode     = SamsungIapHelper.IAP_MODE_TEST_SUCCESS;
    private int     mStartNum    = 1;
    private int     mEndNum      = 15;
    private String  mStartDate   = "20140101";
    private String  mEndDate     = "30140101";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //do your initializations here
         SamsungIapHelper iapHelper = SamsungIapHelper.getInstance( this, mIapMode );
         iapHelper.getItemInboxList( mItemGroupId,
                     mStartNum,
                     mEndNum,
                     mStartDate,
                     mEndDate,
                     this );
     }
     @Override
     public void onGetItemInbox
     (   
         ErrorVo             _errorVo,
         ArrayList<InboxVo>  _inboxList
     )
     {
        if( _errorVo != null &&
            _errorVo.getErrorCode() == SamsungIapHelper.IAP_ERROR_NONE )
        {
            // TODO When inbox list has been loaded successfully,
            //      processes here.

            if( _inboxList != null && _inboxList.size() > 0 )
            {
                     //if you only have 1 item, you can assume that item is purchased, otherwise
                //go over the _inboxList and check
                    //that user has purchased the correct item
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope it helps